# Why can't compiler determine template of std::max with literal?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, compiler-errors, overloading

Neither clang nor gcc, compile this:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
  size_t t = 1;
  t = std::max(t,0);
}
```

giving some error of the flavor:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'max(size_t&,int)'
... note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

If I explicitly provide the template type, it works:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
  size_t t = 1;
  t = std::max<size_t>(t,0);
}
```

It's confusing because neither compiler complains with warnings if I compare `size_t` to `0`, like it would if I compared `size_t` to `int`. Then I infer that the compiler can figure out that it makes sense to compare `0` to `size_t`, so what's stopping the compiler from figuring out which `max` to use?

Comment: Because one argument is a `size_t` and one is an `int`. Explicitly casting the `0` to `size_t` would work too.

Comment: @Yakk, edited. Now it matches.

Comment: Is this different between clang, gcc, or icc?  I don't think I get errors compiling with clang++ but icpc definitely gave an error like:`error: no instance of overloaded function "std::max" matches the argument list

            argument types are: (real, int)` but `std::max<real>` works.  This is new intel oneapi <icc/icpc>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::max` only has one template argument, used for both parameters. When you call the function without explicitly specifying that argument, it tries to deduce it from both arguments, ends up with `size_t` for one deduction and `int` for the other (because those are the types of the two arguments) and doesn't know which one you want.

Pretty sure the part of Clang's error message after the place you cut off says exactly that, though.

Comment: @Sebatsion Redl, Any reason it would have been a bad idea to implement `std::max` using two template parameters? Why not compare a `size_t` to an `int`?

Comment: @mangledorf: Because `T max(T,T)` has a single return type. What would the return type be for `?? max(T1, T2)` ? Consider `std::max(UINT_MAX, INT_MIN)` and `std::min(UINT_MAX, INT_MIN)`.

Comment: @MSalters While it would be possible, for numeric types, to employ some smart template metaprogramming to find the correct type to return (whichever type has the higher max value for `max`, opposite for `min`), the other issue is that `max` actually takes and returns references, and that doesn't work if the two types are different.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: You could of course just decide that the two-type `std::max` returns by value. I wouldn't expect the type with the highest max, though, I'd expect `decltype(T1()+T2())`

Answer (score 0):

The litwral is of type `int`. The template matching (T, T) won't do conversions.